# Manually-Built GCC and Clang; Clang looks at System C++ Paths, not My GCC's

Tags: gcc, clang, gnu-toolchain

**The Question**

How do I make [my custom installation of] clang look at the right spot for C++ headers (i.e. my custom installation of gcc)?

**The System**

I'm currently working on a RHEL 6 computer with all the default libraries.

In a non-system directory, I've [successfully] compiled mpc, mpfr, gmp, cmake, python, gcc (4.9.3 and 8.1.0), and clang (5.0.0 using gcc 4.9.3 and 6.0.0 using gcc 8.1.0).

gcc was configured with `--prefix=... --with-gmp=... --with-mpfr=... --with-mpc=... --disable-multilib`

gcc's (and all its dependencies') bin directories were added to the `PATH`, its lib/lib64 directories added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and CC/CXX set to [my] gcc/g++ respectively.

Then clang was configured with `cmake ../llvm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=... -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLDB_DISABLE_LIBEDIT=True -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CC} -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CXX}`. Note that I set CMAKE_C_COMPILER/CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER even though I shouldn't have to because some other SO answer said they fixed it by doing that, and I figured maybe there's something weird going on, but that didn't fix it.

**The Problem**

If I compile this test file:

```
#include <atomic>

int main ( int , char const** )
{
    std::atomic<int> i (0) ;
    i.fetch_add ( 2 ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I get this result:

```
[redacted]~/Temporary% g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
[redacted]~/Temporary% clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found
#include <atomic>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

In some other code, I have longer include paths which yield more information about the problem. One of them `#include <mutex>` which yields this error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/mutex:45:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/system_error:163:28: error: incompatible operand types ('void (*)()' and 'bool')
    { return _M_value != 0 ? &__not_bool_type : false; }
```

Which clearly shows that it's going to the builtin headers, not the ones that [I've verified] are part of the gcc 8.1.0 installation.

**Other Notes**

I've seen there is a `--gnu-toolchain` option on `configure` (as of 2012) but it does not seem to be present in current versions. I believe I saw the same option at runtime, but requiring users to do that (when they've already sourced something to replace their entire compiler system) is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Tried setting `C_INCLUDE_DIRS` CMake variable efore building Clang?

Comment: Theoretically that affects building `Clang` itself, not where the resultant `Clang` looks to find libraries; right?

Comment: Documentation for that option says `Colon separated list of directories clang will search for headers`. If it would be about the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, I doubt it would be called `Clang`, because it also can be compiled using GCC.

Comment: I didn't notice that. After following that, I found `GCC_INSTALL_PREFIX` in the `config.h` file and when I set that correctly it started working. If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it - I wouldn't have found it if you hadn't mentioned that. -- `cmake ... -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/gcc/install/prefix/` where prefix has the usual `bin`, `lib`, `include`, etc

Comment: Well, if `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` didn't help you should post the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the `clang/Config/config.h` file needs to be updated, which is auto-generated by the cmake process.

Specifically, `GCC_INSTALL_PREFIX` needs to be set.

If you configured your `gcc` install as `../gcc/configure --prefix=/path/to/my/gcc ...` then you should do `cmake ../llvm -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/my/gcc ...`

This then sets clang up to look in the right spot after it's built.